# codeigniter jquery status update - prior updates not showing

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm working on a Facebook-like status update using jquery in Codeigniter. So far, I've got the database, models, controllers, views, and jquery.

My status updates are posting to the database. The **problem is that I can't see the prior status updates in my view (they should be in the #content div)**, instead, when I press submit I get a blank screen (i have php errors turned on, so it's not that). I suspect the problem is in the jquery or the message list view.

**DATABASE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

class Message extends CI_Controller
{

    function index () {
        $this->load->view('default');
    }

function add()
{
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');

            // Add the post
            $this->load->model('message_model');
            $this->message_model->addPost($id, $message);
        }
}

 function view($type = NULL)
{
    $data['messages'] = $this->db->get('message');

    if ($type == "ajax")
        $this->load->view('messages_list', $data);
    else // load the default view
        $this->load->view('default', $data);
}

}
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php 

class Message_model extends CI_Model {

function addPost($id, $message) {
        $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'message' => $message
        );

        $this->db->insert('messages', $data);
}

function get($limit=5, $offset=0)
{
    $this->db->orderby('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    return $this->db->get('messages')->result();
}
}
```

**HTML/JQUERY**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {

        var msg = $('#message').val();

        $.post("<?= site_url('message') ?>", {message: msg}, function() {
            $('#content').load("<?= site_url('message/view/ajax') ?>");
            $('#message').val('');
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">    
    <?php echo form_open('message/add'); ?>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" />
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Update', "class='button'"); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
 <br />
 <br />
<div id="content">
<?php $this->load->view('messages_list') ?>   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**MESSAGE LIST VIEW**
(this is what should load in the #content div; a list of the previous messages--limited to 5 by the model)

```
<ol>
<?php 
if (!empty($message) and (is_array($message)))
 foreach ($message as $message):
?>
    <li><?= $message->message ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You get redirected to a completely different page (blank), or is just the js that blanks the current page?
- And, does it  blank just `#content` or the whole page?
- does the callback function of `$.post()` get called? (Try with an `alert()`)
- Are you sure that `message/view/ajax` is returning the expected html? -> try to see how the request goes by using Firebug console

### Update: avoiding the redirect

It looks like you are not stopping the normal form  submit, and thus page gets reloaded; to prevent this, you should add `event.preventDefault()` to your event handler:

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your code here..
});
```

(or, in your case, in the `.click()` handler for `#submit`, but it would be better to use `.submit()` for the form, if you can uniquely determine its id.. or you can just use `$('#form form').submit( ... )`)

Comment: I get directed to site_URL/message/add (for the function) and the whole screen is blank. Can't see anything in #content. Will check firebug; relatively new to CodeIgniter--how do I try with an alert()?

Comment: problem seems to be on the JS side, not on CI side; I updated the answer, try if it works by adding `preventDefault()`..

Comment: Thanks for your update; but if the ajax loads properly, I shouldn't have to worry about the default, should I? I'm going to focus on message/view/ajax and will check your answer for that suggestion.

Comment: BTW: Always use braces! They make your code a lot clearer - and failproof

Comment: @chowwy no, if you don't prevent default event propagation, form gets submitted no matter what the ajax call returned, or whether it failed..

Comment: Okay thanks. Here's the demo I was trying to replicate (with some modifications. It doesn't open a new page, but doesn't use prevDef either - http://sandbox.littlebrain.org/ci/index.php/message/view

Comment: The demo page you linked is taking a way-too-long time to load; anyways: you can also make your callback return `false` to prevent form submission, but you have to remember to always return `false` in any case; plus unhandled errors make the form to get submitted as the function won't return anything, ... `preventDefault()` is the better and most failproof practice.

Comment: Still doesn't work in my app (the demo I linked to works fine and quickly for me). Am focused on ajax right now, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing:

```
if ($type == "ajax")
        echo $this->load->view('messages_list', $data, true); // send data as string for ajax
    else // load the default view
        $this->load->view('default', $data);
```

Hope it helps